# Powershell: How can you determine which variable in an "if" statement triggered True?

Tags: powershell, if-statement

In powershell, I have code that looks like this.  The intention is to populate a handful of variables with data if a user doesn't supply any:

```
if ($1 -eq $null){$1 = "N/A"}
if ($2 -eq $null){$2 = "N/A"}
if ($3 -eq $null){$3 = "N/A"}
```

Is it possible to condense these down to something like this?

```
if ($1 -or $2 -or $3 -eq $null){
     $FILLER = "N/A"
}
```

Where $FILLER is the variable(s) that returned True?

Edit: For example, if $2 was null but $1 and $3 were not- then the code would assign N/A to $2.

Note: I don't have a problem with the individual if statements, I'm just aiming to condense repetitive code.

Comment: `gv 1,2,3|?{$null-eq$_.Value}|%{$_.Value='N/A'}`

Comment: This worked flawlessly.  If it was an answer, I would accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Get-Variable` cmdlet. That cmdlet return `PSVariable` objects, which represent variables, to you. `PSVariable` objects have `Value` property, which allows you get and set value of variable. So that, you can filter variables which have particular value (`$null`), and then assign new value to them.

```
Get-Variable 1, 2, 3 |
Where-Object { $null -eq $_.Value } |
ForEach-Object { $_.Value = 'N/A' }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `!` to define -eq $null or -eq $false:

```
if (!$1 -or !$2 -or !$3){
     $FILLER = "N/A"
}
```

Comment: That's actually a nice little trick!  However I may not have explained my question correctly.  I need the value "N/A" to be assigned to the value that made the if statement True ($1,$2 or $3).

Comment: `!` (which is short for `-not`) is not exactly the same thing as `-eq $null` or `-eq $false`, but it is often more appropriate than either of them. I don't think this answers the question though.

Comment: if does not return which value of comparison failed because it eventually returning $true or $false. So if one of the `-or` will return $true - then if branch will execute, or skip otherwise.

Comment: @briantist I mean that you can use it in if statement of multiple checks with a readable style, not like `if(($1 -ne $null) -or ($2 -ne $null) -or etc..)`

Comment: @IvanTemchenko understood, and I usually advocate `!` over `-eq $null` as well, it's just that technically it's not the same and won't give the same result in all situations. For readability the statement can also be split up (line breaks are valid after operators like `-and`, `-or`).

Answer (score 1):

You could change the order a bit:

```
$1 = if (!$1) { "N/A" }
```

But what you're really asking, how to determine which of multiple conditions returned `$true` in an `if` statement, is not possible.

If you want to pass an array of values and get back the ones that satisfy a condition, consider `Where-Object`:

```
$result = $1,$2,$3 | Where-Object { -not $_ }
```

If the condition is a string operator like `-match` or `-like` it actually works on arrays already and returns an array:

```
$result = 'apple','apply','ape','zebra' -like 'app*'
```